# Reload directive method after POST in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm developing an opensource app that uses AngularJS as part of the frontend, due to the way that I want it to work (it's paranoid, deleting and adding content from the dom for protection) I've run into a problem that I can't seem to be able to figure out.

The main content of the site is loaded through a service that gathers data from a REST API and populates a directive, the same directive calls a template and renders out the content.

The issue is that when you add new content and the `POST` is successful I'm not able to tell the directive to reload the content, since the `POST` call comes from a controller in a different `$scope`. I've tried with `$watch`, `$apply`, `$push` and lately I've been thinking about `$resource` but I don't think it's the solution. The code is the following:

Directive:

```
  .directive("itemList", function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: "<ng-include src='getTemplateUrl()'/>",
      replace: true,
      controllerAs: 'items',
      controller: function ($http, $scope, sikreAPIservice) {

        $scope.getItems = function (categoryId) {
          sikreAPIservice.getItemsbyCategory(categoryId)
            .success(function (data, status) {
              $scope.category_name = data.category_name;
              $scope.category_id = data.category_id;
              $scope.items = data.items;
              $scope.lockedItem = false;
              $timeout(function () {
                $scope.lockedItem = true;
                $.notify("View time expired. Locking...", "info");
                $scope.getTemplateUrl();
              }, itemTimeout);
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
              $.notify("Couldn't get the item data", "error");
            });
        };

        $scope.getAllItems = function () {
          sikreAPIservice.getItems()
            .success(function (data) {
              $scope.category_name = data.category_name;
              $scope.category_id = data.category_id;
              $scope.items = data.items;
              $scope.lockedItem = false;
              $timeout(function () {
                $scope.lockedItem = true;
                $.notify("View time expired. Locking...", "info");
                $scope.getTemplateUrl();
              }, itemTimeout);
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
              $.notify("Couldn't get the item data", "error");
            });
        };

        $scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
          if ($scope.lockedItem) {
            return '';
          } else {
            return 'includes/items.html';
          }
          $(document).foundation('reflow');
        };
      },
    };
  });
```

Service:

```
  .factory('sikreAPIservice', function ($http) {
    //var mainAPIUrl = 'https://api.sikr.io/v1/';
    var sikreAPI = {};
    sikreAPI.getItemsbyCategory = function (categoryId) {
      return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: mainAPIUrl + 'items?category=' + categoryId,
        cache: false
      });
    };
    });
```

Controller that does the POST:

```
  .controller('ItemsCtrl', function ($scope, $compile, sikreAPIservice) {
   $scope.additem = function (item) {
      sikreAPIservice.createItem(item)
        .success(function () {
          $.notify("Item created", "success");
          $scope.item = null;
          $('#addItem').foundation('reveal', 'close');
        })
        .error(function () {
          $.notify("Can't save the item", "error");
        });
    };
  });
```

The working version is located in http://sikr.io/login.html (this is alpha!, don't store anything important to you as the DB is goign to be wiped out)

The source code is in https://github.com/clione/sikre-frontend/tree/master/assets/js

I agree that maybe the layout of the whole app is not the best, so any guidance to correct it is welcome. If anyone has an idea of how can I make the directive reload the content after the `POST` it would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to $rootScopr.$broadcast when there is a change.  Here is an useful article: http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: @Cerad unfortunately it doesn't work because the digest is in progress, any other ideas?

Comment: Thats a different issue.  Don't broadcast until the promise is resolved.

Comment: @Cerad, can you put your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was provided by @Cerad's comment.

Basically I had to create a broadcast signal that was only captured by the directive and reloaded the contents.

On the controller:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('updateItems', $scope.item.category);
```

On the directive:

```
$scope.$on('updateItems', function (event, data) {
  $scope.getItems(data);
});
```

getItems is a function that calls a service and gets the data.